LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw.lib'
build] LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw.lib' [E:\Z_Dev\OpenGl\build\hello_window.vcxproj]
Please could someone help me add this to my project, I have no idea how to add it through CMAKE and I've tried for so many hours to figure it out myself.
I have attached an image of my project files and the file address for the LIB.
Here is my CMake file:
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello_window VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(hello_window src/config.h src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(hello_window PRIVATE dependencies)

target_link_libraries(hello_window glfw)

target_link_libraries(hello_window lib)
`

Here is my main.cpp:
`#include "config.h"

int main() {
    
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "GLFW couldn't start" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 400, "My_Window", NULL, NULL);
    
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
       glfwPollEvents(); 
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}`

My config.h file:
#pragma once  #include <iostream> #include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 


I have tried adding a LIB folder to my project then using
target_link_libraries(hello_window lib)
But I still get the error, I have no idea how to add it.

target_link_libraries(hello_window lib) attempts to link to a library called lib, you need target_link_directories

Are you building GLFW yourself?

I changed it to link directories, still give mes the error

Try including find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED) after project definition. Also to add library folder you should use target_link_directories(hello_window LIB)

[cmake]   By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
glfw3Config.cmake
glfw3-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
That package was not found

Try removing find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED) and in target_link_libraries instead of glfw write Dependencies/LIB/glfw3.lib

Still giving me errors
[cmake]   Cannot specify link libraries for target "Dependencies/LIB/glfw3.lib" which
[cmake]   is not built by this project.

I used this line
target_link_libraries(hello_window PRIVATE Dependencies/LIB/glfw3.lib)
